# Python : Multiple Values in a single cell of CSV in Insert statement. Getting a missing comma error

Tags: python, sql, csv, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert data from a CSV into a table. In one column of CSV, there is multi value data which when inserted into a INSERT statement gives me a missing comma error.

Example Values:

```
Column1,Column2
Wizard,(Read,Write)

val1 = row[header.index("Column1")]
val2 = row[header.index("Column2")]
```

`"INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ("+str(val1)+","+str(val2)+")"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use bind variables you won't have those difficulties and you also avoid the very real possibility of SQL injection as well! Something like this:

```
cursor.execute("insert into Table1 values (:1, :2)", [val1, val2])
```